# DBImage does not Refresh programmatically

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I am stumped! D5ent.
I have a form with a dozen design-time SpeedButtons on them.
I have a dataset with the Caption, the Hint and a Glyph for all twelve buttons.
When I run the database I can assign the Caption, Hint, select and store a Bitmap for the Glyph.

When I use the DBNavigator to step through, it correctly shows the individual DBImage with each Bitmap for each button. However at runtime, not so.

I have this code that steps though the dataset and when I ShowModal the form all of the buttons have the correct individual Captions and Hints, but they all have the same Glyph from the first button.

```
procedure LoadButtons;
  procedure SetButton(var aBtn : TSpeedButton);
  begin
    aBtn.Hint:=tblButtons.FieldByName('Hint').AsString;
    aBtn.Caption:=tblButtons.FieldByName('Caption').AsString;
    aBtn.Glyph.Assign(dbimgButton.Picture.Bitmap);
  end;
begin
  tblButtons.First;
  BtnCtr:=1;
  repeat
    case BtnCtr of
      1  : SetButton(btn1);
      2  : SetButton(btn2);
      3  : SetButton(btn3);
      // ... to twelve
    end;
    tblButtons.Next;
    Inc(BtnCtr);
  until tblButtons.EOF;
end;
```

end;

Where am I going wrong? I have messed with Update, AutoDisplay, LoadPicture etc...

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. I have not yet received any answers.

Comment: Remove DisableControls, I don't know what 'dbimgProgram' is but if it's a db-aware control then it is not updated because of DisableControls.

Comment: AAAArrrggghhhhhh Thanks Sertac. No beer for me tonight!

Comment: You've received answers to your other questions, and haven't accepted any of them as being right (or even the most helpful).

Comment: @Sertac, nice psychic debugging. There was no mention of `DisableControls` in the code. :) You should post an answer - you appear to be right.

Comment: @Ken - Done. Even if I'm not right, it may be helpful to someone else. :)

Comment: @MarjanVenema, I prefer people who read the guidelines for the location they're asking for **free** help, and follow those guidelines to show they appreciate the effort put into that **free** help. <G>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `DisableControls` then db-aware controls are not updated while looping through the dataset. If you're assinging the glyph from such a control then that's the reason why all buttons have the glyph of the first record.

Comment: +1 for the pyschic debugging skills. Nice catch, and the OP has said in comments above you nailed it. :)